# Resolving spring profile before servlet startup for dynamically reading configs from local or spring boot config server

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've integrated spring cloud config server in my non-spring boot app by extending `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` and overriding `createEnvironment()`.
In my application I set the `spring.profiles.default` in `web.xml`. When the value is *prod* I want to fetch the configs from config server and when the value is *local* I want to load the configs from local property file.

The problem is when I'm calling `acceptsProfiles()` on `StandardServletEnvironment` since the `ServletConfigPropertySource` is a Stub, its not returning default profile value specified in the `web.xml`. I suppose later, during refresh the stub will be substituted by the actual class. Calling `acceptsProfiles()` is for knowing if *prod* profile is active to connect to the config server or go to the local properpty file.

This is causing problem for me because I want to dynamically create `Environment` based on the default profile.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue.

**Update**
Instead of relying on the context parameter for finding out the active profile I decided to pass a system variable to set the active profile and override `customizePropertySources` of `AbstractEnvironment` to load proper property sources.

The reason for doing it programmatically is to have control over the ordering of the property sources. Based on Spring doc of [`PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) it is mentioned that

> In certain situations, it may not be possible or practical to tightly control property source ordering when using `@ProperySource` annotations ... it is recommended that the user fall back to using the programmatic PropertySource API. See `ConfigurableEnvironment` and `MutablePropertySources`

Please refer to the code below

```
@Override
protected void customizePropertySources(MutablePropertySources propertySources) {
    super.customizePropertySources(propertySources);
    loadBootstrapProperties(propertySources);
    if (isAppConfigLocal()) {
        try {
            propertySources.addLast(new ResourcePropertySource("appEnvironmentSpecificProperties", getLocalPropertyName()));
            propertySources.addLast(new ResourcePropertySource("appCommonProperties", assembalePropertyName(LOCAL)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not locate local PropertySource(s)", e); 
        }
    } else {
        PropertySource<?> source = initializeConfigServicePropertyLocator(this);
        if (source != null) {
            propertySources.addLast(source);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why so complex? a simple `@Profile` should be enough to either include or not. Also you shouldn't be doing this instead you should use an `ApplicationContextInitializer` check in there and register additional `PropertySources` you shouldn't mess around with the context.

Comment: @M.Deinum, The approach you are suggesting might work. But just bear in mind that based on documentation its not possoble to have control on the ordering when using *@PropertySource*. Please refer to the update section above.

Comment: I nowhere mentioned `@PrpoertySource`. As I stated what you are doing is something you still should be doing but in a separate component which exists especially for this use case.

Comment: You are right. I misread your comment. Could you elaborate more. What do you mean by a separate component ?

Comment: You shouldn't have extended `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` what you should have done is create a class implementing `ApplicationContextInitializer` and register that in the web.xml. The `ApplicationContextInitializer` is specifically designed to modify the context before starting it.